# How to access a class member for a class of generic type?

Tags: java, generics

I am new to Java generics, but if I can manage to access the members of a generic class type, I could solve a bunch of tasks with a few methods. The starting point is that I have several types of data which all need similar processing.

Is there is a way to access a member on a generic type like in the following toy example?

```
public void <O> someMethod(AbstractData d, Set<String> filter) {
    List<O> list = d.getKeys();
    for (O o : list) {
        if(filter.contains(o.id)) { // < cannot access member of generic type O
            doSomeWork(o);
        }
    }
 }
```

Everything besides the access of o.id seems to work.

Comment: You need to tell java that O will be of some type like so `public void <O extends MyType> someMethod(...`

Comment: And of course, to not deal with raw types, or unchecked casts, you also need to look into the interface that AbstractData is providing; as `getKeys()` should then return a `List<O extends whatever>` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal way would be for your generic class to extend an interface. If you already know that every object of the generic class has an id, declare `<O extends Identifiable` where `Identifiable` would be something of the likes :

```
public interface Identifiable {
    int getId();
}
```

If you can't have the generic class extending an Interface, try using reflection.